# While reading snowflake table in pyspark dataframe, column name is read in double quotes?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created a table as "create table test ("Male/Female" String, Age Integer)". Now it gives different results in below scenario:

1. Running below query on Snowflake.
   select * from test
   **Male/Female**    Age
2. Reading table as data frame pyspark on databricks.
   df1 = spark.read.format("Snowflake").option("query","select * from test").load().show()
   **"Male/Female"**  Age

I want the first result (without double quotes), while reading the dataframe. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll give yourself a lot fewer of these types of headaches if you can manage to get rid of special characters in your object/column names.

Comment: It is quite likely that double-quotes are added in `df.show()` method. Have you tried to print column names using `df.columns()`

Comment: @AndreiLuksha I tried using df.printSchema() as df.columns() is giving error that "'list' object is not collable". But df.printSchema() also giving the same result (i.e. adding column name with double quotes)

Comment: @DavidGarrison Yes I also prefer not to use special characters, but it's the project requirement, so I need to add it.

Comment: @Madman: Try `print(df.columns)`. Looks like in pyspark .columns is a field, not a method.